# Cannot set maxvar in Stata

Tags: stata

When I run `set maxvar 32000`, Stata errors:
`no; dataset in memory has changed since last saved`

I save the dataset. So I think the error is not the case.

Comment: What version of Stata are you running? The maximum number of variables in Stata IC is 2048. See `help memory`.

Comment: I have the same problem on Stata MP running on a big virtual machine -- no idea how to solve this

Answer (score 1):

At the time that you issued the `set maxvar` command you had a dataset in memory, and that may cause your data to be cleared and possibly lose some of your work. So issue the `set maxvar` command when you have no data in memory.

Comment: Thank you so much @NickCox. You're right and it worked.